# Strip caption from image using css

Tags: views, theming

I am adding a caption to images by using the following module: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption

For the front page I am using views. There, I also show the images but I do NOT want to show the captions. I guess the captions can be stripped away by using CSS...

How is that done? I do not know CSS and the "interaction" of Drupal and CSS very well.

My questions:
1. Where do I have to add the CSS code?
2. What do I have to write there?
3. How is this CSS snipped included in views to get the effect of stripping caption away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if this is strictly a css question, I believe it's off-topic here, but...

I've never worked with that module, so this may or may not be an option:

If you output your View as a table, you can modify how fields are represented. Unless the module overwrites the default image formatter, you should be able to choose the Image formatter instead for that field and bypass the module.